# Which PHP frameworks are worth comparing with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony, comparison

I am writing master thesis about new PHP frameworks. I want to compare S2 with ZF2 but Zend is still beta so it will be not fair to compare it with stable Symfony 2.

What frameworks are you suggests to compare with Symfony 2?

Comment: You can compare *any* framework to any other framework. What are your criteria for "comparability"?

Comment: "New?" I can't think of a major framework that qualifies as "new." I'd say in order to compare the major frameworks, you'd need to have used them at least nominally. Maybe you should start there?

Comment: ZF2 is still beta, but ZF1 is stable. From your question I infer that because Symfony has a V2 and ZF has a V2, that it would be an apples to apples comparison? It would not, it's just coincidence that they happen to be in the same version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of CakePHP 2.0

People also seem to like Kohana and CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

Well... the level of Symfony2 complexity cant really be compared to any other framework :D
I like Symfony, but man, it took me 2 hours to configure the configuration :)

Even Zend is easier to use and gives you power to build mvc as you like it.

I think Symfony2 is too hyped and they are doing all those benchmarks to show how they framework is the best and I dont like that. There is nothing you can accomplish in Symfony2 and you cant in other great frameworks.

Back on your question:
If I ware you, I would take a look at these:
Yii: [LINK](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
FuelPHP: [LINK](http://fuelphp.com/)

These two are great new frameworks.

Basicly whats going on with frameworks you could write about:
1. They are starting to dispatch HTTP Request Object, so dispatcher is aware of HTTP request method, and accept parameters. So you can write RESTFUL apps.

1. The same thing is with response, they are not joust echoing or loading view instead they can return HTTP response object that holds both your content and you can set HTTP status codes like 404... so you can have more power on what are you returning.
2. They all use some kind of ORM, Symfony2 uses Doctrine.

These are first things that cross my mind when thinking about new frameworks.

And you should take a look at Django, Rails, Pylons... and other web frameworks that come from other programming languages, it would be nice to compare them...

Symfony is also great dont get me wrong, and I have all resepect for Fabian and his great work.